# How can 'community' edit posts?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, community-user

I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14920231/672989) answer, it has an edit by  '[Community ♦](http://'https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community')'.

This was [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14920231/revisions) (bold is added):

> You access the <s>the</s> property **in** the wrong way.

But [Community ♦](http://'https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community'), is a background process right, at least it claims it is on it's profile:

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!

Pretty nice edit for a bot right? 
Or wasn't it a bot?

Comment: From the faq under "Who can suggest an edit?": *Anonymous users can suggest edits to any post more than 10 minutes old. These edits are attributed to the Community user upon approval.*

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the answer, that explains it! I disagree that this questions is a duplicate. The answer can indeed be found in that answer, but that does not make the questions duplicates..

Comment: Here is MSE it is.